# Angular routing setup gives "is not a function" error

Tags: angularjs

I get this error `Error: Argument 'readingController' is not a function, got undefined.` and nothing renders on the page. What have I done wrong?

```
var app = angular.module('Tutorials', ['functions', 'ui.utils', 'tutorials']).controller('main', function($scope, $element, Position, Romanize) {
$scope.sectionNumber = Position.sectionNumber;
$scope.tutorialNumber = Position.tutorialNumber;
$scope.questionNumber = Position.questionNumber;
$scope.sections = sections;
$scope.currentMaterials = []
    $scope.currentMaterial = "";

var readingController = function($scope, Romanize) {
    $scope.currentMaterials = $scope.sections[$scope.sectionNumber].tutorials[$scope.tutorialNumber].material;
    $scope.currentMaterial = $scope.currentMaterials[$scope.questionNumber];
    $scope.getRomanization = function(Romanize) {
        Romanize.get($scope.currentMaterial).then(function(d) {
            $scope.romanized = d;
        });

        $scope.$apply();
    };
    $scope.getRomanization(Romanize);
    $scope.$apply();

    $scope.checkRomanization = function(userRomanization) {
        if ($scope.romanized === userRomanization) {
            $scope.questionNumber++;
            $scope.getRomanization(Romanize);
        };
    }
};

$scope.loadFromMenu(0, 0, true);

}).config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
$routeProvider.when('/grammar/Reading/Basic Vowels', {
    templateUrl: '/grammar/Templates/Reading.html',
    controller: 'readingController'
}).when('/test/secondTab', {
    templateUrl: '/js/test/angular/views/secondTab.html',
    controller: 'SecondTabCtrl'
}).otherwise({
    redirectTo: '/'
});

$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
}]);
```

Comment: Try to declare your controllers using `.controller('name', function(){})` on your module

Comment: There are some syntax errors with too many curly braces. Additionally, `readingController` is defined inside of another controller and is not a valid angular controller.  I would suggest cleaning up the syntax and indentation and going from there.

Comment: I think that's just copy paste errors as this is cut down from the original code.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an other example organizing your controllers (or anything else for your app):

```
angular.module('MyApp', [])

.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider
    .when('/', { controller: 'MainCtrl' })
    .when('/first-page', { controller: 'FirstCtrl' })
    .when('/second-page', { controller: 'SecondCtrl' });
}])

.controller('MainCtrl', ['$rootScope', '$scope', function ($rootScope, $scope) {
  // ...
}])

.controller('FirstCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
  // ...
}])

.controller('SecondCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {
  // ...
}]);
```

Or maybe inside an own file eg. foobar.js

```
angular.module('MyApp').controller('FoobarCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
  // ...
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Angular looks for controllers that are defined inside an angular module.

You've defined the controller function, but you need to tell angular about it:

```
app.controller('readingController', readingController)
```

Or, like one of comments to your question suggests, just define the controller function inside the call to `controller`:

```
app.controller('readingController', function($scope, Romanize) {
  // controller stuff
});
```

Comment: The problem I have is that the reading controller (and all the other individual view controllers) need to access data from the main controller which they are declared inside. This is essentially user state data and needs to be accessible throughout the app. I was following a structure suggested by this post https://github.com/mgonto/specs/wiki/Angular's-project-structure but perhaps I've misunderstood.

Comment: First, I'm not convinced that the approach described there is all that great (though I just skimmed it), but you are misunderstanding what is meant by "one controller inside another". He means declaring that in html: `<body ng-controller="Main"><div ng-controller="InsideMain"></div></body>`, NOT in the JS. The `$scope` that gets created for the `InsideMain` controller will prototypically inherist from the `$scope` of `Main`. The controllers still have to be declared as normal on the angular module.